# size mismatch, m1: [1 x 512], m2: [25088 x 4096] at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:2070

Tags: deep-learning, vgg-net

Goal: Use pretained VGG16 to classify CIFAR-10 Images.

Please, see this link to have an overview:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10Wo95j3h7h7QMd8Xpueb50ieawxw5b4M